# WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager Apache Config

Tags: apache, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm having problems accessing the website of the WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager server. I have opened port 9443, but when I type `localhost:9443/emm` I get `page not found`.

What configuration do I need to change in the apache server to point it to the correct place. I am unsure what the root directory of the website is.

```
Ollie

Details:

Debian Jessie 32bit

WSO2-EMM Version 1.1.0

Apache 2.4.10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the binary version 1.1.0 of WSO2 EMM, `localhost:9443/emm` should work after you execute `{EMM_HOME}/bin/wso2server.sh`.
If it is not working, please check the log file which is located at `{EMM_HOME}/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log` for the reason of failing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such specific changes to be done to Apache server when you install & run the WSO2 EMM. Can you log into carbon console?

https://localhost:9443/carbon/